# How does POSIX distinguish files from directories?

Tags: file, directory, posix, file-attributes

How does POSIX distinguish files from directories?

On DOS and Windows, a directory is nothing more than a file with the D attribute. I tried to figure out how to differ them on POSIX-compatible operating systems like Linux and BSD, but it doesn't look as a quick and simple task. (This is probably because I don't use such an operating system, and therefore cannot test anything myself.)

I ask this question to improve my manual about naming files. Currently, it has the following passage:

> Directory names can also be referred as file names; directories are nothing more than files with the D attribute.

I'm not sure this quote would be correct for POSIX.

Comment: At its core, a directory is simply a file that contains directory entries, and directory entries are just information that associate a filename with a file.  Beyond that, you're dealing with filesystem-specific information.  While it's likely that directories are tagged differently from other files in any given filesystem (if that filesystem supports subdirectories), it's not necessarily referred to as the "D attribute".  The OS doesn't exactly matter when you're talking about a filesystem-specific attribute/mode.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system identifies files by what is known as an inode, stored  in inode tables based on the types of files, rather than by their names or locations in directories. A device is also filename and stored in the directory /dev/ (e.g. /dev/ttyn)

Comment: Hmm. I just found (https://www.elated.com/understanding-permissions) that actually UNIX and Linux are actually use the "D" attribute to distinguish directories (same as on Windows). A quote from the link: _"There is also a D attribute on the left, which tells us if this is a file or a directory (folder)."_ Maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: "_This string of letters, `drwxrwxrwx`, represents the permissions that are set for this folder. (Note that these are often called attributes by FTP programs.)_" It's not necessarily called a D attribute in other cases. [The documentation for the `ls` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) states `d` is simply the "entry type" character used to denote directories in the "file mode" field and other characters are used for various other kinds of files. IMO, feel free to use "D attribute" as long as you clarify what you mean in the context of a POSIX system.